# Update Oracle table from another table value on matching case

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I have a main table (say tableA  which has columns tab_a_id, field_code , field_id). There is another table, say tableB which has columns area_id , area_code. tab_a_id is a primary key of TableA.  I want to update  field_id of tableA based on field_code. field_code of tableA and area_code of tableB are matching but not identical, mean field_code has other values which are not matching with area_code column. I want to set field_id = area_id if field_code = area_code but, if not matched it should set to default value -1 which is 'unknown' field. I tried with subquery and bulk update (e.g Update tableA SET field_id = (SELECT area_code from tableB where area_code = field_code)). This worked for limited set of data. But I have 3 Million matching records , which means 3 million subqueries. Another problem is there are 7 million records, resulting 4 million unmatched records & useless subqueries.
Is there any optimal way to update such records with minimum time and better efficiency. I tried merge command but it has poor performance compare to forall loop query

Comment: I can't follow the question.  Sample data, desired results would help.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. (Constraints, indexes & plans are critical.) Please research before considering posting. That includes basics of SQL optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Updating 3 out of 7 million rows seems to be the problem here.

I've created a test set in a database on a small machine, and the fasted way to get your results is to create a new table (CTAS) with the desired data and later swap names. I have not used the primary key column tab_a_id to simplify the answer.

```
CREATE TABLE a (field_id NUMBER, field_code VARCHAR2(30)) NOLOGGING;

CREATE TABLE b (area_id NUMBER, area_code VARCHAR2(30)) NOLOGGING;
```

Using `MERGE` and `UPDATE` is quite slow (15 minutes), presumably because of the amount of changes:

```
UPDATE a SET field_id=-1 WHERE field_code NOT IN (SELECT area_code FROM b);
5,599,989 rows updated. (560 seconds)

MERGE INTO a USING b ON (a.field_code=b.area_code)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET a.field_id = b.area_id;
2,400,011 rows merged. (232 seconds)
```

However, creating a new table with the changed data is 20 times faster and takes only 38 seconds:

```
CREATE TABLE x NOLOGGING AS 
SELECT a.field_id, NVL(b.area_code, -1) AS field_code
  FROM a JOIN b ON a.field_code=b.area_code;
```

Here is the test data generation:

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO a (field_id, field_code) SELECT id, to_char(id) from (select level as id from dual connect by rownum <= 1000000); COMMIT;
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO a (field_id, field_code) SELECT field_id+1000000, to_char(field_id+1000000) from a; COMMIT;
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO a (field_id, field_code) SELECT field_id+2000000, to_char(field_id+2000000) from a; COMMIT;
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO a (field_id, field_code) SELECT field_id+4000000, to_char(field_id+4000000) from a; COMMIT;
EXEC dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(null, 'a');

INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO b (area_id, area_code) SELECT -field_id, field_code FROM a SAMPLE (30);
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(null, 'b');
```